# How to create single page search form with ajax in MVC Razor

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm a beginner in the ways of MVC / Razor... Basically I have 2 pages just for showing a search result from an API that I'm consuming with Json.

Index.cshtml: (Just a form)

```
@model ConsultaInterna.Models.SearchApi

<div class="jumbotron">
<h2>Consulta Interna</h2>
Placa
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))
{
    <input asp-for="Model.Name" class="form-control" name="name" id="txtName" />
    <input class="form-control" type="submit" id="ok" />
}
```

and Search.cshtml (Which also have the form. I want to leave just this page, right now I can't because if I load directly from Search.cshtml it gives me an error like

"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0. " (Obviously because I'm trying to load labels with a null search)

this is Search.cshtml

```
@model ConsultaInterna.Models.SearchApi

<div id="loader" class="spinner" style="display:none">OIE</div>

<div class="header formPesquisa">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    LoadingElementId = "loader",
    UpdateTargetId = "resultado"

}))
{
    <input placeholder="Placa" asp-for="Model.Name"  name="name" id="txtName" width="30" />

    <input class="pesquisa" type="submit" id="enviar" value="Ok" />
}
```

```
<div class="panel">Placa @Model.Name</div>
<div class="panel">Last Name / Model.LastName</div>
```

ALSO Important, the Ajax form isn't working properly... the loader won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to move your loader div into the `Ajax.BeginForm`.
2. You need also need to add the `resultado` div to display your result.

   ```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new AjaxOptions()
   {
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       LoadingElementId = "loader",
       UpdateTargetId = "resultado"

   }))
   {
       <div id="loader" class="spinner" style="display:none">OIE</div>
       <input placeholder="Placa" asp-for="Model.Placa" class="pesquisa placa" maxlength="7" name="placa" id="txtPlaca" width="30" />
       <input placeholder="CPF" asp-for="Model.CPF" class="pesquisa cpf" maxlength="11" name="cpf" id="txtCPF" />
       <input class="pesquisa" type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />
       <div id="resultado"></div>
   }

       <div class="panel">Placa @Model.Name</div>
       <div class="panel">Last Name / Model.LastName</div>
   </div>
   ```

You also need to make sure you have added the relevant reference to the specific unobtrusive ajax library. As an example:

**BundleConfig**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
  "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
  "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

**_layout.cshtml**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

**Example controller action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string placa, string cpf)
{
    return new JsonResult { Data = "found", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

[image: Image showing ajax returned]

Comment: the "resultado" div was me trying to create something like na "updatepanel". Right now the search result is showing up  on those last 2 divs:

<div class="panel">Placa @Model.Name</div>
    <div class="panel">Last Name / Model.LastName</div>